# Member "Is-A" Person or Person "Has-A" Enrollment

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I am trynig to create a set of Models for our Enterprise App.  It has never had them being tied very tightly to the Databases.  At this point I am trynig to simply answer the "Is-A" or "Has-A" questions.  I am basing this off the DB structure but I do not want to, neccesarily, be tied to that.

For starters I have the, very, obvious Person model with the typical "Has-A" Phone and Address.  Almost everything works off of that Person model and is a "Has-A".

However, we have Members.  In our DB/Current System a Member is a Person who has an Enrollment.  To be specific an Enrollment of a certain type that is Dis-Enrolled(*by Date*).

On one hand I feel that Member would Inherit form Person as a "Is-A" relationship.  However I am very new to this type of thing and I wonder if I am over thinking it.  Does my Person "Has-A" Enrollment or does that imply something else?

It makes me wonder, if I do have a Member should I have different "Is-A" models for Pre-Enrollments, Enrollments, Former Enrollments?  It seems that is more a question of State but again, I am new at this.  If it is a question of state am I back to just having a Person model that "Has-A" Enrollment?

I understand this is, somewhat, opinion based and I welcome each persons opinion on this.

Comment: Enrollment sounds like an [association class](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/) (especially since you mention several enrollments - pre, former, etc.). What's missing in that case is the "in what" of the enrollment (e.g., a Plan of some kind?).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: So it sounds like you believe my Person Class "has-a" enrollment(s) using the aforementioned "association class" versus me having a Member class that inherits from my Person class...I think I agree.  I will apply the concept to my models and see what it looks like.  Like your linked example Enrollments have a Date Range that makes this seem like a no brainer.

Comment: Is-a doesn't makes sense to me, for same reasons mentioned by @Alex Burtsev in his answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense that Person be higher up in the heirarchy.  From the group of all People, you have some members, some ex-members, and some members-to-be.

If you try to look at it the other way and say From the group of all Members, all are people...but some are Dis-Enrolled?  It makes less sense that way since if they are Dis-Enrolled, then they are no longer members.

Unless being a Member and Enrollment are not connected (ie. if you can be dis-enrolled and still be a member).

Comment: To your last statement, No, though you can have things in the System that could only apply to a Member even though you are a Dis-Enrolled Member.  That's why it almost feels like a "State" to me but what do I know since I had to ask in the first place.

Comment: To your first statement, maybe I am misunderstanding, but I too think Person should be higher up.  What I meant to ask was should my Person have Enrollments or should I have a Member that Inherits from Person that has Enrollments.  Additionally I am wondering how I manage the whole "State" thing. 
That make more sense?

Comment: You certainly do know! This is your program afterall.  Few questions:
1) can you have multiple enrollments?
2) can you have multiple memberships?

I am not sure how you would manage state, you probably should determine what you want to do with members/enrollment first.

Comment: Yes you can have multiple enrollments.  Having an Enrollment makes you a Member.  Whether you are a Pre-Enrollment Member, Member, or Former Member though.

Comment: It seems to me enrollments are important here.  Since if you are enrolled then you are a member, then you can catch all members in enrollment: Person A has enrollments (implies membership.  Person A's enrollments are x,y, and z.  Person B was enrolled, Person B's previous enrollments are x,y, and z.  Person C is pre-Enrolled, and Person C's pre-Enrollments are x,y, and z.  From that you can tell that membership is simply a description of the states of enrollment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll try to answer you question though I don't fully understand what is "Enrollment" (I'm not native english speaker) I guess it some kind of Membership.

Suppose you will decide to use IS-A relationship, so you would end up with:
Member:Person, VIPMember:Member, ExMember:Member, etc. What would you do if you Person object changes to Member or anything else? You will have to convert you object to this type, create a Member object copy values from Person object... thats lots of boilerplate work.

If Object changes it Type after it's creation better use some property to distinguish it's type. Cosider Apple : Fruit (Apple is always Fruit, it can't become Tomato), and CanceledOrder : Order (Order can become CancledOrder so I would prefer Order.State). This is especially true for languages when once the object is created you can't change it's type (like C#).

As for your case from what I understood I would create:

```
public class Person
{
    public IEnumerable<Membership> Memberships {get;}

    public bool IsMember 
    {
        get
        {
            return Memberships.Any();
            //Or what ever logic you imply
        }
    }
}
```